# NSCache EXC_BAD_ACCESS when evicting objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, crash, exc-bad-access

First off: I've looked through the other `NSCache`-related posts on SO and haven't found anything similar to my issue.

The top crash in my crash logs reveals a background thread attempting to evict objects from an `NSCache` (Stack trace attached).

My codebase was inherited from a 3rd party, and it's *messy*... there are several `NSCache` objects scattered throughout the app in a global scope... so I'm not sure where to start.

Some noteworthy information from my crash reporting tool (Crashlytics):

1. 95% of crashes occur with the app in focus
2. Our app is using ARC.
3. Crashes happen on all supported OS (iOS7, iOS8)
4. Through all the `NSCache` implementations I can find via global search in our code, we're never setting the cache object's `delegate` (nor does the selector `cache:willEvictObject:` appear in any of our code or 3rd party code. *However, one of the 3rd-party static libraries we use very well could be*.
5. The stack traces of the other application threads always contain *some form* of message about a memory warning.

   - No other pattern has emerged from looking at the neighboring threads' stack traces.
6. Analytics that track the sequence of user's screen views in the app have wildly differing trails -- there's no particular view controller whose usage is causing trouble.

The message from my crash report indicates its failing when trying to call the method `cache:willEvictObject:`, which is defined by `<NSCacheDelegate>`.

[image: crash log]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm seeing this also. Did you make any headway?

Comment: Nothing!  Curious, does your project link against either the New Relic SDK or TestFlight SDK?  I'm wondering if either of those could be my culprit.    (I still need to remove the TestFlight SDK since they're shutting down the service).

Comment: No neither. Hockey, Omniture, CoreData, MapKit. I'm seeing it exclusively for iOS 8 though.